# I am studying computer science but I am passionate about electronics

Tags: career-path, computer-science, job, electrical-engineering

I am studying CS but I am passionate about electronics and hardware. However, I can't study CS and EE at the same time. So if I study electronics by myself with online courses, can I work in that field after graduation?

Comment: You can work everywhere you want, IF an employer takes you. The employer takes you if you can convince them that you can solve problems. Whether you can convince them of that depends on what you know and have studied. The answer to your question is "Yes, it is possible." but this will probably not help you because it is just as broad as your question. Also this would fit more into Workplace Stackexchange, if at all.

Comment: You should look into computer architecture, and take as many relevant courses as you can.

Comment: Patricia Shanahan if i did it would it be useful ?

Comment: Why can't you go into EE or computer engineering? In the U.S., at least, computer science department enrollments are generally currently oversubscribed, while EE departments don't have enough students. If the place where you're studying has an EE department, why wouldn't they let you transfer?

Comment: my score is 91% and  EE department requirements is score above 93%
Iam not in U.S.

Comment: @JoeAdel I don't know whether it will be useful or not. That will depend on luck, as well as your own abilities. Computer architecture is the aspect of hardware development that is closest to computer science. I worked for several years for as a server architect, with degrees in mathematics and CS, not EE.

Comment: "I can't study CS and EE at the same time" [citation needed]. Anecdotally off topic, at my alma mater, it was not unusual for undergraduates to double-major in EE and CS, as you could do so with only 3-4 additional courses if you planned your studies right. A handful of students even triple-majored in EE, CS, and math sci AKA applied math. These were usually students who had matriculated with at least a semester's worth of credits already, so they had room to spare in their schedules. OTOH, if OP's question is about graduate school, then it's on topic and this comment is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine came out of university with a piece of paper saying he's electrical engineer. He has a bachelor in electronics but now what he's doing is virtualization, servers and networks, absolutely not related to what he studied (actually he told me that low level languages he learned were helpful for understanding how optimization works, but that's it), and he earns pretty well! I think your degree will matter only for a short period of time in the beginning, but if you can get a job in a field even if it's different from you education, you can use it to continue learning in that field by yourself. Your degree won't be the most important thing for your future employers, experience will.

Answer (score 2):

Engineering tends to be pretty strictly regulated in terms of accreditation. It's much easier to be a software developer with an EE degree than the other way around.

If you want to do EE, try to switch to EE.

Comment: That may depend on what country you're in.